# need to extend two classes somehow

Tags: android

I am creating an app which has a dashboard layout as its home screen and each icon opens a seperate activity.

I have an abstract class called DashboardActivity which has methoda such as what to do when the home button in the title bar is pressed etc.

I then have various classes such as 'hotels' which will display a list of hotels. This class extends DashboardActivity but I also need it to extend ListActivity because it will be a list but I know that this can't be done.

What workaround can I use to overcome this problem?
Thanks

Comment: Why can't DashboardActivity extend ListActivity?

Comment: but I have other activities such as Map which will need to extend MapActivity

Comment: then why not define a DashboardActivity as an Interface instead of a class?

Comment: so would that mean I have to implement all the methods of DashBoardActivity in every class I use?

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problem. The way I solved it was make a base class for each. DashboardListActivity and DashboardActivity. I'm not sure of a better way. Then in List activities, just extend DashboardListActivity.

There might be a better way, but I don't know it. Of course, you have dual maintenance on these two base classes so there is a trade off.